# How to conditionally use another provider given a boolean value?

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

So I have a widget that can either be used to create/edit a template or use a template to fill information, and I use a boolean flag `isSession` which is true if we are filling a premade template. I currently have a parent widget with a ProviderScope overriding the unimplemented provider which looks like this:

parentWidget -> templateWidget

```
templateProvider.overrideWith(
          (nestRef) => isSession ? ref.read(sessionTemplateProvider.notifier) : TemplateProvider(template: template, isSession: isSession),
)
```

which either uses the sessionTemplateProvider if its a session, or creates a new TemplateProvider if its supposed to create/edit a template. If I launch a session once its fine, but if I launch a second time I get the following error:

> StateError (Bad state: Tried to use WorkoutTemplateEntityProvider after `dispose` was called.
>
> Consider checking `mounted`.

Not sure what exactly is the best pattern to use either one of the providers. Would rather not have to make the conditional at every single call site where I have to reference the provider in the child widget. I saw ProxyProvider but wasn't sure if that was relevant. Any help is appreciated!

For reference all the providers are StateNotifierProviders

Tried adding .autoDispose to the providers but it didn't work and I get the same error. I assume something is happening where it's disposing the created TemplateProvider when we exit, and the reference to the sessionTemplateProvider somehow gets lost.

Comment: In general, you should be using override only for testing.  And you should not be using StateNotifier[Provider] either.